# Bind value of input radio into ng-repeater to webSql database

Tags: angularjs, web-sql, onsen-ui

This is my code. The DOM returns `undefined` for `input radio[name="Dispense"]` after calling function `AggiungiProdotto()`.

HTML part:

```
<ons-list ng-controller="ListaDispense">
        <ons-list-header>Seleziona Dispensa</ons-list-header>
        <ons-list-item modifier="tappable" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-repeat="item in items">
          <label class="radio-button radio-button--list-item">
          <input type="radio" name="Dispense" id="{{item.id}}" ng-model="IdDispensa" ng-value="{{item.id}}">
          <div class="radio-button__checkmark radio-button--list-item__checkmark"></div>
                {{item.NomeDispensa}} 
          </label>
        </ons-list-item>
      </ons-list>
```

Javascript Part

```
    $scope.AggiungiProdotto = function() {
            var t = $scope.IdDispensa; //$("input[name=Dispense]:checked").val();
            var n = $scope.nomeProdotto; //$("#nomeProdotto").val();
            var d = $scope.DataScadenza; //$("#DataScadenza").val();
            var g = $scope.GiorniPreavviso; //$("#GiorniPreavviso").val();

            if(n==undefined || t == undefined){
                ons.notification.alert({message: 'Inserisci il nome del prodotto e/o categoria!'});
                return false;
            }
            else{
            dbRemindUse.transaction(function(e) {
                var i = "INSERT INTO prodotti (nome, iddispense, datascadenza, giornipreavviso) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
                e.executeSql(i, [n, t, d, g], function() {
                     ons.notification.alert({message: 'Prodotto Inserito'});
                }, error)
            })
        }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of scope problem ng-repeat creates it's own scope that is not available to controller (only for primitive type).

You can solve it by two ways

First:- Use $parent with model.

```
 <input type="radio" name="Dispense" id="{{item.id}}" ng-model="$parent.IdDispensa" ng-value="{{item.id}}">
```

Second:- Create object of model:-

```
$scope.object={
IdDispensa:""
}
<input type="radio" name="Dispense" id="{{item.id}}" ng-model="object.IdDispensa" ng-value="{{item.id}}">
```

Small fiddle for understanding 
http://jsfiddle.net/7e27har1/

Comment: Looks like you beat me by 10 seconds... I'll delete my answer

Comment: Hi, thanks for help, i use the First:  <input type="radio" name="Dispense" id="{{item.id}}" ng-model="$parent.IdDispensa" ng-value="{{item.id}}"> but the result is "undefined" in my script for this $scope var t = $scope.IdDispensa;

Comment: Try second one i dont know why first is not working for you but second is more general

Comment: thanks, I have resolved to end with the first solution, when I called the function to click the button was not included in ng-cotroller, now all ok thanks, I'm a beginner, but I'm falling in love AngularJS :)